# Can using Little Snitch make my mac Less Secure than its "out of the box" settings?

Tags: network, security, firewall

**Short Question**
Im thinking about configuring little snitch to allow all processes incoming and outgoing network traffic.

By allowing "any process” incoming / outgoing rights will this make my Mac less secure than its default settings (default out of the box, eg. not using OSX’s in built firewall tool)

**Longer Question with background**

The reason i want to do the above is because i want to block incoming and outgoing network traffic for a few applications. I can do this no problem with Little Snitch, but if i turn Little Snitch on it will by default block all network traffic and require each connection to be manually approved. To get around this i would setup the "allow any process" incoming and outgoing traffic rights.

This way all incoming / outgoing is allowed as a global rule, but certain apps are blocked as a specific rule.

Would doing the above make my Mac less secure than its default settings (default out of the box, eg. not using OSX’s in built firewall tool)

Comment: yes it can. you can accidentally block processes/addresses needed for system updates, and maybe also not notice that. and when some security issues in macos are found and fixed, you will not receive updates and…

Comment: You may as well just uninstall it as set it to that; in effect, any process, both directions is 'off'.

Comment: @SargeBorsch i was actually referring by "allowing all processes" to incoming / outgoing traffic rights does this make the system less secure ?

Comment: @Tetsujin please see updated question

Comment: In that case it will work like any firewall - allow all *except* named. Then if you manually add all your exceptions, you can then switch it to Silent Mode & Allow.

Comment: thanks @Tetsujin - so will having little snitch setup like this make my mac any less secure than if i didnt have little snitch setup and if i didnt have the default firewall enabled ? As the mac would have been brand new out of the box ?

Comment: No, George's answer is still true, however you set up Little Snitch.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry still not understanding, do you mean : No its not as a secure. OR No, using little little snitch as set out above is still as secure.

Answer (score 2):

Little Snitch can work alongside macOS firewall. If a connection is permitted by Little Snitch, but is still blocked in the macOS firewall, it'll still be blocked. Little Snitch doesn't bypass the macOS firewall, so Little Snitch can't lower the security when the macOS firewall is still enabled.